# NetBeans (8.0.2) can't communicate with Wildfly 9 (Final)

Tags: java, netbeans, wildfly

If i start a Wildfly 9 Server with NetBeans, it does not detect that it is started. If i start again, i get the error message "WildFly 9.0.0 Start Failed. HTTP Connector port 8080 is already in use."

The port is used by Wildfly. Wildfly is started by NetBeans but not detected.

(If i stop Wildfly manually, i can start it again with no error message, but NetBeans does not detect it. If i try to start again, i get the error message "... port 8080 is already in use.")

Why can't NetBeans detect the running Wildfly instance?

Answer (score 3):

Netbeans support for WildFly 9 and 10 that is in the workings, it was added to latest builds that will be part of 8.1 Netbeans release.

For time being best thing to do is to try the nightly builds where it works.

you can grab nightly builds from http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/

Comment: the nightly builds i tried raised a lot of exceptions

Answer (score 2):

"NetBeans 8.1 beta" was released and includes support for Wildfly 9 and 10: https://netbeans.org/community/releases/81/

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this behavior, I tried it too. AFAIK Wildfly support in Netbeans was maintained by plugin created directly by JBoss community. This changed in Netbeans 8.0.2 and now it is part of Netbeans installation package. Problems with support of newly released versions of Wildfly is occurring quite often.

- Here for Wildfly 8: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=241805
- Here for Wildfly 8.1: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=245297

I would suggest to wait until they add support for version 9, or you can try proactively raise the bug in Netbeans bugzilla.

Comment: So using wildfly 8.x until netbeans supports wildfly 9.x properly. Netbeans "8.1 To be released in October 2015 "

Comment: Great. If you think my answer is correct, go ahead and set my answer as the right one.

Comment: i dont have enough reputations

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue on a windows 7 machine with netbeans 8.2 (8.1 as well) and wildfly 9.0.2.
Actually the issue came from an entry in my hosts file configured to map localhost to the actual machine ip address. The issue was fixed as soon I removed that entry.

Hope this will help.